# Using Java to turn Letters into numerical counterparts

Tags: java, encryption

I have to create a cipher program that shifts the letters of a message up and down according to a key. After thinking awhile I figured I would read in each character from a string, convert it to its numerical value (a=1, b=2) add the shift amount and turn back into a character to be printed out.

I know how to handle if I try to shift 3 past z(wrap around) I just didn't know how to do the actual conversion. I can also handle it if it turns out 'a' is 37, just takes adjusting numbers.

Any idea on the actual syntax? Been tearing apart API's and the Internets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a character you can do this

```
char out = (char)(in + shiftAmount);
if(out > 'z') {
   out = (char) ('a' + (out - 'z' - 1));
}
else if(out > 'Z' && out < 'a') {
   out = (char) ('A' + (out - 'Z' - 1));
}
```

Comment: I love you thiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiis much xD. Problem solved elegantly.